# Java library for encoding/decoding audio files, such as mp3 and mp4

Tags: java, maven, encoding, mp3, mp4

Could you please provide me some non-deprecated java library for usage in maven repository for encoding/decoding audio files, such as mp3 and mp4?

What I need exactly is to convert mp3 to mp4 on the fly and vice versa.

I've found some JAVE (http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/), Xuggler (http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/), but seems these projects are no more alive.

Answer (score 2):

MP4 is just a container format for audio and video data. One supported audio format for MP4 is MP3, so you need no transcoding, you can simply wrap your MP3 data into an MP4 container file if that really is what you want.